# Output mysql data in single line to screen

Tags: mysql

I have a column:

```
Id          attrib                value
"id1"      "Router"             "New York"
"id2"      "Router"             "New York"
"id3"      "Router"             "New York"
"id4"      "Router"             "New York"
```

How can I possibly `select` the `attrib` and `attrib_value` values only once, but include all the relevant Id's with a select statement? something like:

```
"Router"   "New York"   “id1, id2, id3, id4”
```

I have tried a few things but I am not even sure what to search for on the internet.. The below is as far as I got

doing a straight select gives the values in standard format:

```
select id, attrib, attrib_value from table where attrib=Router
```

Comment: If appropriate, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, the problem here is that it needs to be queried externally from a scripting language, so the answer below solved my issue. Thanks for your reply, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `group_concat()`

```
select group_concat(id), attrib, attrib_value from table 
where attrib='Router'
```